# How to create loop where answer of first calculation is part of equation for second calculation etc

Tags: r, loops, equation

I am trying to create a loop in R that runs for 10 stages (say 10 years) when the results from year 1 are incorporated into the calculation for year 2 etc.. I'm sure this should be easy to do but I don't know if this type of calculation has a specific name so I haven't known what to search for..

so I'm basically going for something that would do the following:

```
(a*1.5)-(b*4)=c
(c*1.5)-(b*4)=d
(d*1.5)-(b*4)=e
```

etc... 
until you get the result of the tenth stage, but to organise it all as one equation

Comment: Can you show what `a` and `b` look like? Note that `d` equals `((a*1.5)-(b*4)*1.5)-(b*4)` and so you can calculate the value of `e` also.

Comment: So 'a' is the starting amount of a resource (in this case 5000kg), 'a*1.5' is the amount the resource grows by each year, 'b' is the population of an animal (300), and 'b*4'(kg) is the amount of resource the animal population will consume. I'm hoping to later put this into a shiny app so those figures will vary with input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing is simply called an iterative calculation.  You could do it like this:

```
a <- 2
b <- 3   # Replace these with your real starting values
for (i in 1:10) {
  a <- (a*1.5) - (b*4)
  print(c(i, a))
}
```

The `print` statement isn't needed, but helps to show what is happening at each step:  your iteration diverges with those starting values.

```
[1]  1 -9
[1]   2.0 -25.5
[1]   3.00 -50.25
[1]   4.000 -87.375
[1]    5.0000 -143.0625
[1]    6.0000 -226.5938
[1]    7.0000 -351.8906
[1]    8.0000 -539.8359
[1]    9.0000 -821.7539
[1]    10.000 -1244.631
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks for this! How would you then use this equation e.g how would you plot it directly, or is it just a calculation that you would have to turn in into a dataframe first?

Comment: That's completely up to you.  If you're not sure what to do,  you'll need to ask on a different site, e.g. Cross Validated (stats.stackexchange.com).  Once you know what you want to do, if you don't know how to do it, you could ask here.